# Computing $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Perhaps this is known but I could not find an answer in standard textbooks.

Is there a standard way to compute a sum of the kind
$$S(a)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{(n^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\,,\qquad a>0\,,$$
or more generally an (absolutely convergent) infinite sum $\sum_n f(n)$ when $f(n)$ has branch cuts?
If it had only poles it would have been fairly easy...

Thanks in advance for the hints!

Comment: I see no reason to expect this has a closed form.  Even for $a=1$.